Why don't defects have an effective charge in metals?
In semiconductors and insulators, crystal defects, e.g., vacancies and interstitials, are treated as having an effective charge. In metals, however, defects are treated as neutral. I can expect that this is due to things like metals being conductors and having no band gaps. However, I cannot formulate a physically rigorous argument to justify this. Any help in this aspect would be appreciated.

Pretty much correct. Defect states in an occupied band won’t be seen, defect states above the conduction band don’t matter.

If you can add a formal answer, I would really appreciate it.

These are the best arguments I can think of so far:

Metals have a high density of delocalized free electrons. If a charged defect existed in a metal, the free electrons in the metal would immediately rearrange themselves to neutralize its charge.
Metals don't have a band gap, i.e., the electronic bands are contiuous. Thus, adding or removing an electron would not create a stable charged defect because the electron would quickly redistribute itself among the available states. More specifically, adding (or removing) an electron would add it (or remove it from) the Fermi level.

I don't know if my words are physically rigorous, so corrections are welcome.
